# crispy-forms add javascript sum of fields

Tags: javascript, django, django-crispy-forms

I want to sum groups of select choice result dynamically in my template.
all forms are select fields like this (models.py)

```
evolQuote = (
    (1, 'High'),
    (0, 'Undetermine'),
    (-1, 'Low'))
cycleMarket = models.IntegerField(choices=evolQuote, null=False, blank=False, default=0)
news = models.IntegerField(choices=evolQuote,null=False, blank=False)
```

my template is:

```
 {% load crispy_forms_filters %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
<head>
  <style>
      input {max-width: 10em};
  </style>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    // function
$("form select").on("change", function() {
  console.log("say hello")
  sum = 0;
  //loop through selects
  $(".select").each(function() {
    console.log($(this).val())
    sum += Number($(this).val());
  });
  console.log(sum)
  $("#fundamentals").val(sum);
})
</script>
</head>
<h3>Valuation {{ typeVal }} </h3>

          <form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
            <div class="col-md-8">

                <div class="row">
                      <div class="col">
                        <h7>Market trend</h7>
                      </div>
                    <div class="center">
                      <input class="speech-bubble" value="0" id="marklRate" name="markRate">
                    </div>
                </div>


               <div class="form-row border">

                    <div class="form-group col-md-2 mb-0" name="market-1">
                     {{ form.cycleMarket|as_crispy_field }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-2 mb-0" name="market-2">
                      {{ form.news|as_crispy_field }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-3 mb-0" name="market-3">
                      {{ form.managementPostion|as_crispy_field }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-2 mb-0" name="market-4">
                    {{ form.short|as_crispy_field }}
                    </div>
                </div>
              <br>
               <div class="row">
                      <div class="col">
                           <h7>Analysts advice</h7>
                      </div>
                    <div class="center">
                      <input class="speech-bubble" value="0" id="analRate" name="analRate">
                    </div>
                </div>

                  <div class="form-row border" >
                    <a href="https://www.barchart.com/stocks/quotes/{{ stck.codeBarchart }}/overview" class="form-group col-md-3 mb-0" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" name="analyst-1">
                      {{ form.BARCHART_analysts|as_crispy_field }}
                    </a>
                    <a href="https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/{{ stck.codeTradingviews }}" class="form-group col-md-4 mb-0" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" name="analyst-2">
                      {{ form.TRADINGVIEW_analysts|as_crispy_field }}
                    </a>
                    <a href="https://www.investing.com/{{ stck.codeInvesting }}" class="form-group col-md-3 mb-0" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" name="analyst-3">
                      {{ form.INVESTING_analysts|as_crispy_field }}
                    </a>
                  </div>
                <br>
                <div class="row">
                      <div class="col">
                         <h7>Indicators</h7>
                      </div>
                    <div class="center">
                      <input class="speech-bubble" value="0" id="indRate" name="indRate">
                    </div>
                </div>
                  <div class="form-row border" >
                      <div class="col col-md-2 mb-0" name="indicator-1">
                        {{ form.parabolics|as_crispy_field }}
                      </div>
                      <div class="col col-md-2 mb-0" name="indicator-2">
                        {{ form.trix|as_crispy_field }}
                      </div>
                      <div class="col col-md-2 mb-0" name="indicator-3">
                        {{ form.arron|as_crispy_field }}
                      </div>

                      <div class="col col-md-2 mb-0" name="indicator-4">
                      {{ form.macd|as_crispy_field }}
                      </div>
                      <div class="col col-md-4 mb-0" name="indicator-5">
                      {{ form.moving_average_cross_up|as_crispy_field }}
                      </div>

                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="row">
                      <div class="col">
                        <h7>Graphs</h7>
                      </div>
                    <div class="center">
                      <input class="speech-bubble" value="0" id="graphRate" name="graphRate">
                    </div>
                </div>

                  <div class="form-row border" >
                    <div class="form-group col-md-4 mb-0" name="graph-1">
                      {{ form.graph_trend|as_crispy_field }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-4 mb-0" name="graph-2">
                      {{ form.graph_support|as_crispy_field }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-4 mb-0" name="graph-3">
                      {{ form.graph_mean15_30|as_crispy_field }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-4 mb-0" name="graph-4">
                    {{ form.candels|as_crispy_field }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-4 mb-0" name="graph-5">
                    {{ form.confirm_figure|as_crispy_field }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-4 mb-0" name="graph-6">
                    {{ form.graph_weeks|as_crispy_field }}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <br>
                  <div class="row">
                      <div class="col">
                        <h7>Fundamentals</h7>
                      </div>
                    <div class="center">
                      <input class="speech-bubble" value="0" id="fundamentals" name="fundamentals">
                    </div>

                  </div>
                  <div class="form-row border" >

                      <div class="form-group col-md-3 mb-0" name="fundamentals-1">
                        {{ form.fond_PE|as_crispy_field }}
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-md-3 mb-0" name="fundamentals-2">
                        {{ form.fond_Profit_NextYear|as_crispy_field }}
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-md-3 mb-0" name="fundamentals-3">
                        {{ form.fond_Profit_NextYear_dollars|as_crispy_field }}
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-md-3 mb-0" name="fundamentals-4">
                      {{ form.fond_revenues_NetYear|as_crispy_field }}
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-md-4 mb-0" name="fundamentals-5">
                      {{ form.fond_revenues_NetYear_dollars|as_crispy_field }}
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-md-4 mb-0" name="fundamentals-6">
                      {{ form.fond_BARCHART_analyst_estimates|as_crispy_field }}
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-md-4 mb-0" name="fundamentals-6">
                      {{ form.date_BARCHART_earnings|as_crispy_field }}
                      </div>
                    </div>
                <br>
              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save">
            </div>
          </form>


{% endblock content %}
```

my attempt javascript:

```
function sumamount(){
    sum=0;

    $("input[name^='market-']").each(function(){
        sum+=Number($(this).val());
    });
    console.log(sum)
    $("#fundamentals").val(sum);
}
```

But console log sum equals zero all the time.
[image]

Please find generated code from first form-group (cyclMarket field):

```
<div class="form-group col-md-2"> name="market-1">
    <div id="div_id_cycleMarket" class="form-group">
         <label for="id_cycleMarket" class=" requiredField">
                    CycleMarket<span class="asteriskField">*</span>
         </label>
    <div class>
    <select name="cycleMarket" class="select form-control" id="id_cycleMarket">
      <option value="1">High</option>
    
      <option value="0" selected="">Undetermine</option>
    
      <option value="-1">Low</option>
    
    </select>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Cryspy generates code but not visible in my template. and don't know if it can see my group-form names?

Comment: Hi , what is html generated of `{{ form.cycleMarket|as_crispy_field }}` line ?

Comment: I add a picture of what it is now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your *onchange* event is on div not on input field instead as you are already using jquery you can change your selector to `$("form select").on("change",..` this will get called whenever select inside form will changed and then use  `$(".select")..` to iterate through selects inside div .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
//on change of selct
$("form select").on("change", function() {
  sum = 0;
  //loop through selects
  $(".select").each(function() {
    console.log($(this).val())
    sum += Number($(this).val());
  });
  $("#fundamentals").val(sum);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post">
  <div id="div_id_cycleMarket" class="form-group">
    <label for="id_cycleMarket" class=" requiredField">
                CycleMarket<span class="asteriskField">*</span>
     </label>
    <div class>
      <select name="cycleMarket" class="select form-control" id="id_cycleMarket">
        <option value="1">High</option>

        <option value="0" selected="">Undetermine</option>

        <option value="-1">Low</option>

      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="div_id_news" class="form-group">
    <label for="id_news" class=" requiredField">
                news<span class="asteriskField">*</span>
     </label>
    <div class>
      <select name="news" class="select form-control" id="id_news">
        <option value="1">High</option>

        <option value="0" selected="">Undetermine</option>

        <option value="-1">Low</option>

      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="div_id_managementPostion" class="form-group">
    <label for="id_managementPostion" class=" requiredField">
                managementPostion<span class="asteriskField">*</span>
     </label>
    <div class>
      <select name="managementPostion" class="select form-control" id="id_managementPostion">
        <option value="1">High</option>

        <option value="0" selected="">Undetermine</option>

        <option value="-1">Low</option>

      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  fundamentals :
  <input type="text" id="fundamentals">
</form>
```

Comment: Hi In my code it says :ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $

Comment: I don t think this will work with crispy_forms as crispy manage name of fields in my template

Comment: we are just using `input` here as a selector that should not cause problem . It would be more clear if you can show html generated code  of your form .

Comment: just edit my question above this crispy first group-form. all of my fields are based on same generated html code

Comment: thanks for helping :-) but not working. function is not called.

Comment: I update my code with template...to help understanding issue...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228995/discussion-between-swati-and-philippe-haumesser).